# Next.js pretty seo url passing query parameters

Tags: next.js

I have a product page with path `product/[id]/index.js`. I would like to 'prettify' the product  url for SEO purposes. I would like the url to look like `product/usb-mouse-black` instead of `product/121122-001` I need to pass the query ID to populate the product details.

slug=usb-mouse-black

```
  <Link as={`/reservas/${slug}`} href={{pathname: `/product/[id]`, query: {id: idkey}}}>
    <Button disableElevation size="small" className={classes.button} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(event) => { return true }}>Solicitar Disponibilidax</Button>
  </Link>
```

ID=121122-001

Then I try to get the ID :

```
 const { id } = router.query
```

Currently getting `usb-mouse-black` as ID instead of `121122-001`

Answer (score 0):

I just use the `Link` in it's most simplified form:

```js
<Link href={`/product/${idkey}`}>
    <Button disableElevation size="small" className={classes.button} variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={(event) => { return true }}>Solicitar Disponibilidax</Button>
  </Link>
```

Remember that `/reservas/[id]/index.js` is the same as `/reservas/[id].js` no further configuration is necessary

Comment: and how do you pass parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The only parameter I found in your question was the `idkey`. idkey is already in the url

Comment: Thanks for following up! I don't want to show the product id in the url. I don't want to show `xxx.com/121122-001`, I want to show a descriptive title for the product eg.:`xxx.com/usb-mouse-black` and send the ID to the redirected page so I can populate the product details, any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If the objective is to hide the product id from users you may use the `as` attribute to send a nicer looking URL. if the objective is SEO you should consider saving the `slug` into the DB. so instead of id you can send the slug and use that as the key to fetch the record.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to parse the product name on `product/[id]/index.js` rather than specifying in the `Link` tag. It will improve the SSO effect in Google and other search engines.

```
const { slug } = router.query
const id = parseSlugToId(slug);
```

If you still prefer your way, try this:

```
<Link as={`/product/${slug}`} href={`/product/${idkey}`}>{ /* your code goes here */</Link>
```